# How to doctest functions with volatile output?

Tags: python, unit-testing, docstring, doctest

By the time the doctest is run, the volatile output is different thus the test fails. Ideally (but not necessarily), the solution should try to avoid to write testable code outside the docstring in order to avoid impacting the test coverage.

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_now():
    """
    >>> get_now()
    datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 13, 20, 26, 44, 258862)
    """
    return datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to assert than an effect occurred, so you should patch datetime and assert that `now` was called.

This is untested and may not work, but should illustrate the idea:

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_now():
    """
    >>> from unittest import mock
    >>> my_module.datetime.now = lambda: datetime(2018, ...)
    >>> get_now()
    datetime.datetime(2018, ...)
    """
    return datetime.now()
```

Comment: I understand. However, the end user when calling `?get_now` will be shown the code related with mocking as well. Is it possible to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid it with the additional constraint about not adding code outside the docstring. You could also refactor this to be a deterministic function that takes the source of randomness as a parameter. `def get_now(now): return now()`

Comment: I this case, I probably prefer to mock the doctests outside the docstrings. If you know the answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I don't know the solution off hand, but I suspect you'd need to extend the doctest runner to handle the mocks you need.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to expose a "private" `_now` parameter. For example:

```
def get_now_year(_now: datetime | None = None) -> int:
    """
    >>> from datetime import datetime
    >>> now = datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 13, 20, 26, 44, 258862)
    >>> get_now_year(_now=now)
    2018
    """
    now = _now if _now is not None else datetime.now()
    return now.year
```